# ID field intermittently lost in custom point class

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'm building a C++ program which needs to handle geometry. I have been trying to get `boost::geometry` to work, but I am having the following issue. My points need to maintain an ID value or other identifying tag (I need to link them to properties stored in other objects). I can successfully register this point using `BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET` and carry out `boost::geometry` operations, however the moment I carry out any operations with it `boost::geometry` seems to create new copies of my point without the id value.

Is there something I'm missing about using `boost::geometry` with custom points that would make it possible to do what I'm trying to do, or do I have to re-think my approach and find some other way to do what I'm trying to do?

The following code shows an example point class (`int id` is the identifier) and also a sample of code which compiles and runs (with appropriate `#include` and `namespace` declarations) however it keeps removing my point IDs:

point class:

```
class My_Point
{
public:

    My_Point(const My_Point &p);
    My_Point(double x = 0.0, double y = 0.0, int new_id = 0);

    const double Get_X() const;
    const double Get_Y() const;

    void Set_X(double new_x);
    void Set_Y(double new_y);

    const int Get_ID() const;
    void Set_ID(int new_id);

private:
    int id;
    double x;
    double y;
}
```

copy constructor:

```
My_Point::My_Point(const My_Point &p) {
    Set_X(p.Get_X());
    Set_Y(p.Get_Y());
    Set_ID(p.Get_ID());
}
```

test code:

```
void TestPolygon()
{
vector < My_Point > p;

p.push_back(My_Point(0.0, 0.0, 0));
p.push_back(My_Point(1.0, 0.0, 1));
p.push_back(My_Point(1.0, 1.0, 2));
p.push_back(My_Point(0.0, 1.0, 3));
p.push_back(My_Point(0.0, 0.0, 4));

cout << "Initial points are:\n";

for (int i = 0, n = p.size(); i < n; i++)
{
    cout << point_to_string(p.at(i)) << "\n";
}

detect_enter();

polygon<My_Point> poly;
append(poly, p);

//this code gives each point with an incorrect id of 0
cout << "Polygon points are:\n";

for (int i = 0, n = poly.outer().size(); i < n; i++)
{
    cout << point_to_string(poly.outer().at(i)) << "\n";
}

detect_enter();

strategy::transform::rotate_transformer<degree, double, 2, 2> rotate(45.0);

for (int i = 0, n = poly.outer().size(); i < n; i++)
{
    transform(poly.outer().at(i), poly.outer().at(i), rotate);
}

vector<My_Point> p2;
p2 = poly.outer();

//this code gives an incorrect id of 0.
cout << "Final points are:\n";

for (int i = 0, n = p2.size(); i < n; i++)
{
    cout << point_to_string(p2.at(i)) << "\n";
}

detect_enter();

//this code gives the correct id values as expected.
cout << "Original points were:\n";

for (int i = 0, n = p.size(); i < n; i++)
{
    cout << point_to_string(p.at(i)) << "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: What does your copy constructor do?

Comment: Thanks for asking Neil. The copy constructor code is:

    My_Point::My_Point(const My_Point &p)
    {
    Set_X(p.Get_X());
    Set_Y(p.Get_Y());
    Set_ID(p.Get_ID());
    }

Comment: If all you do is a straight copy, you shouldn't provide the copy constructor. It will generate one automatically.

Comment: Thanks Neil - if I comment out the copy constructor I still have the same issues, so that's not where the problem lies.

Also, I obviously don't have the hang of using Stack Overflow's comment formatting yet given my inability to get the code in my previous comment to format properly...

Comment: *"Also, I obviously don't have the hang of using Stack Overflow's comment formatting yet..."* - you should add the relevant information to your question. You can do so by clicking the *Edit* link.

Comment: You're missing the crucial bits in the code, which is obviously how you adapted the `My_Point` type for use as a Boost Geometry model.

Answer (score 3):

As sehe pointed out, the library only knows how to access X and Y coordinates of My_Point. Furthermore, the rotate_transformer only knows how to rotate the geometrical part of your Points, it isn't aware that you're storing IDs and that you'd like to copy them. You could try to write your own strategy for this. Something like (not tested):

```
struct my_rotate_transformer
    : public strategy::transform::rotate_transformer<degree, double, 2, 2>
{
    typedef strategy::transform::rotate_transformer<degree, double, 2, 2> base_t;

    my_rotate_transformer(double angle)
        : base_t(angle)
    {}  

    template <typename P1, typename P2>
    bool apply(P1 const& p1, P2& p2) const
    {
        p2.Set_ID(p1.Get_ID());
        return base_t::apply(p1, p2);
    }
}
```

It's similar to the way how `std::transform()` can be used. You must pass a `UnaryOperation` which transforms the elements of a Range the way you like it. In Boost.Geometry strategies are used for this purpose.

Btw, it's a simple case, you could just manually copy/set the IDs.

Another thing is that `bg::transform()` works for arbitrary Geometry so you could just pass Polygons there (however you need another Polygon for this):

```
polygon<My_Point> poly_in;
polygon<My_Point> poly_out;
bg::transform(poly_in, poly_out, my_rotate_transformer(45))
```

Using `append()` you can directly append Points to Polygon. There is no need to use temporary `std::vector`, I think.

Also, have in mind that some algorithms creates entirely new Geometries, containing new Points, e.g. `intersection()` or `convex_hull()` so IDs probably shouldn't be copied, or not all of them.

And last but not least, I'm guessing that some algorithms may cause problems in your scenario, it probably depends on the algorithm. So feel free to ask questions. Consider also subscribing to Boost.Geometry mailing list. It's a good place for getting in touch with the developers, proposing new features, reporting bugs, etc.

Comment: Nice. I was seriously wondering how this could be done. Do you think the Point concept (and adaptations) should be extended to allow for "rich" points? I understand that many applications would be foolish to have "heavy" point types, but in the case of the application that just wants to leverage existing algorithms on small geometries... It felt a bit like a C callback API without a `void* userdata` argument to me

Comment: @sehe It probably depends what exactly we'd like to do with those heavy points. Only to propagate this extended part in mutable algorithms? It could be useful only for mutable algorithms, but not all of them. Set operations creates different geometries so points probably shouldn't be propagated. What's left is `transform()` and `simplify()`.

Comment: Problem is, right now there is _no_ way to associate metadata from source geometries with output geometries (e.g. from a convex hull, intersection). Going by the coordinates is brittle, especially with duplicate/shared points or floating point values. I'm really not sure how to make this kind of thing reliable.

Comment: I was trying to find the code I remembered dealing with attached information to multipolygons in a [mailing list thread](http://boost-geometry.203548.n3.nabble.com/intersection-of-two-vectors-of-polygons-td2875513.html#a2880997) but sadly the codepad.org samples have been lost. I think it had a very generic "binary transform" algorithm (?)

Comment: @sehe For `transform()` and `simplify()` algorithms maybe it'd be convenient to provide 1-geometry version (`transform(in_out_geometry, strategy)`) preserving the original points. We could also consider adding some kind of a View/Adaptor allowing to access transformed geometry on-the-fly (`polygon | transformed(strategy)`). Though it'd suffer form the same limitation since the original `polygon` wouldn't be modified, new Point would be generated and returned. And this is another potential problem, this transformed geometry would have rvalue points. Anyway, any proposal is welcome.

Comment: Ah yes, `convex_hull()` could also benefit from it. `intersection()` not so much because often new points are generated lying somewhere in the middle of the segments, and for intersecting vertices we wouldn't know which one should be propagated.

Answer (score 1):

You carry out a `BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET`. The thing is, this tells the library how to set the x and y values. It never tells the library how to set an ID value (or that it is even there).

So, the library will simply construct an identical point, logically, by using the setters for x and y, and of course, you'll be stuck with no id.