# boost::geometry::difference providing custom point with attributes

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I'd like to use 2D points with attributes for the polygons.

The attributes should be assigned to any new points according to some kind of strategy.

Do you know if it is possible and how to do it?
Is there any doc describing how to do it?

Comment: I happen to think the question is quite well-expressed and should be immediately clear to users of Boost Geometry. Of course, a small, trivial code sample could be nice, but hardly adds any value here (plus people might come up with "solutions" for that address the one specific example, instead of the general question as posed)

Comment: Ok, need reopen votes to be able to vote as dupe `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: That linked dupe is "the horse's mouth", Wulkiewicz is one of the library maintainers

Answer (score 0):

Last time I looked at things it proved impossible. That's because the library does construct new points using the available (accessor) traits.

Similar/related questions:

- [ID field intermittently lost in custom point class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056414/id-field-intermittently-lost-in-custom-point-class)

In fact, let me dupe-vote that!

Comment: I might find the previous discussions on SO/mailing lists that lead to this conclusion. Have to run now