# boost geometry with user defined point type looses additional properties

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I have a set of points (`merged_data`) on which I want to run RDP algorithm. So I create a `boost::geometry::model::linestring` with my vector of merged_data. The merged_data have some parameters other than x, y coordinates equivalent properties.

It seems that copy constructor of `merged_data` is not invoked. Instead the default constructor is invoked then only the coordinate related properties are being set when I construct a `linestring` model from my user defined point. So long before I can run RDP algorithm on my set of points, all other properties are lost.

Following is an example code [(cpp.sh/7otfd)](http://www.cpp.sh/7otfd) that reproduces the issue.

```
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>

struct gps_coordinate{
    double lat;
    double lng;
};

struct merged_data{
    gps_coordinate location;
    std::string label;
};

namespace boost { namespace geometry { namespace traits {

template<> struct tag<merged_data> {typedef point_tag type;};
template<> struct dimension<merged_data> : boost::mpl::int_<2> {};
template<> struct coordinate_type<merged_data> {typedef double type;};
template<> struct coordinate_system<merged_data> {typedef boost::geometry::cs::spherical_equatorial<boost::geometry::degree> type;};
template<> struct access<merged_data, 0>{
    static inline double get(merged_data const& p) {return p.location.lng;}
    static inline void set(merged_data& p, double const& value) {p.location.lng = value;}
};
template<> struct access<merged_data, 1>{
    static inline double get(merged_data const& p) {return p.location.lat;}
    static inline void set(merged_data& p, double const& value) {p.location.lat = value;}
};
}}}

int main(){
  std::vector<merged_data> complicated{merged_data{gps_coordinate{1, 2}, "Hallo"}, merged_data{gps_coordinate{3, 4}, "World"}};
  boost::geometry::model::linestring<merged_data> complicated_polyline;
  for(auto m: complicated){
    std::cout << boost::format("(%1%, %2%) @%3%") % m.location.lat % m.location.lng % m.label << std::endl;
    boost::geometry::append(complicated_polyline, m);
  }
  std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
  for(auto p: complicated_polyline){
    std::cout << boost::format("(%1%, %2%) @%3%") % p.location.lat % p.location.lng % p.label << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In this example `label` attribute is lost. In my actual problem I have many other attributes that I want to retain.

```
(1, 2) @Hallo (3, 4) @World


(1, 2) @ (3, 4) @
```

**WORKAROUND**

A simple trick worked. After creating the linestring I need to set the additinal attributes. Rest of the work will go fine.

```
for(int i = 0; i != complicated_polyline.size(); ++i){
   complicated_polyline[i] = complicated[i];
}
```

In my actual problem I am using this linestring and applying `RDP` algorithm on it which filters out a subset of points in `simplified_polyline`

```
boost::geometry::model::linestring<stmr::merged_data> complicated_polyline, simplified_polyline;
for(auto m: complicated){
    boost::geometry::append(complicated_polyline, m);
}
for(int i = 0; i != complicated_polyline.size(); ++i){
    complicated_polyline[i] = complicated[i];
}
boost::geometry::simplify(complicated_polyline, simplified_polyline, th/earthRadiusKm);
std::vector<stmr::merged_data> simplified;
for(auto p: simplified_polyline){
    simplified.push_back(p);
}
```

Comment: Having stepped through the boost code this seems to be by design. When points are copied the only thing copied is the coordinates.

Comment: So if I want to preserve others attributes of my own point type I can't just use boost-geometry ? I need to use something like an auxiliary lookup table indexed spatially? But that invites another problem. What if I have two points with same coordinates.

Comment: Someone here saying it's impossible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451296/boostgeometrydifference-providing-custom-point-with-attributes. I would agree.

Comment: Hm I also think the same. Is there a way I use the rdp implementation of boost and somehow glue it with my own strategy ?

Comment: Fond an workaround. Please check update.