# ID field intermittently lost in custom point class when using boost::geometry::append

Tags: c++, boost-geometry

My question is very similar to the one asked in [ID field intermittently lost in custom point class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056414/id-field-intermittently-lost-in-custom-point-class/53924028#53924028).

In my case, I have two polygons (each with points that have a type represented by an int attribute) on which I want to perform a union operation which results in a new polygon. I'm hoping that there is a way in which the points in the union polygon that come from an existing polygon keep their type. Is there any way to achieve this?

If it is not possible, I could of course work around this by using ids.

I already tried to use a polygon with customized points but it seems that not even the append operation works.

Here is my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

//#define BOOST_GEOMETRY_DEBUG_HAS_SELF_INTERSECTIONS
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;

class QPoint
{
public:
  double x;
  double y;

  int id;
  QPoint() { }
  QPoint(double x, double y) : x(x), y(y), id(0) { }
  QPoint(double x, double y, int id) : x(x), y(y), id(id) { }
  QPoint(const QPoint& p) : x(p.x), y(p.y), id(p.id) { }
};

namespace boost {
namespace geometry {
namespace traits {
// Adapt QPoint to Boost.Geometry

template <>
struct tag<QPoint>
{
  typedef point_tag type;
};

template <>
struct coordinate_type<QPoint>
{
  typedef double type;
};

template <>
struct coordinate_system<QPoint>
{
  typedef cs::cartesian type;
};

template <>
struct dimension<QPoint> : boost::mpl::int_<2>
{
};

template <>
struct access<QPoint, 0>
{
  static double get(QPoint const& p) { return p.x; }

  static void set(QPoint& p, double const& value) { p.x = value; }
};

template <>
struct access<QPoint, 1>
{
  static double get(QPoint const& p) { return p.y; }

  static void set(QPoint& p, double const& value) { p.y = value; }
};

template <>
struct access<QPoint, 2>
{
  static int get(QPoint const& p) { return p.id; }

  static void set(QPoint& p, int const& value) { p.id = value; }
};
} // namespace traits
} // namespace geometry
} // namespace boost

int main()
{
  //using point = bg::model::point<float, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>;
  using polygon = bg::model::polygon<QPoint, true, false>; // cw, open polygon

  polygon green;

  bg::append(green.outer(), QPoint(0.0, 0.0));
  bg::append(green.outer(), QPoint(10.0, 0.0));
  bg::append(green.outer(), QPoint(10.0, 10.0));
  bg::append(green.outer(), QPoint(0.0, 10.0));

  std::cout << "Points polygon green:" << std::endl;
  for (auto& p : green.outer())
  {
    std::cout << "x: " << p.x << ", y: " << p.y << ", id: " << p.id << 
  std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The output I get is:

```
Points polygon green:
x: 0, y: 10, id: 4
x: 10, y: 10, id: 4
x: 10, y: 0, id: 4
x: 0, y: 0, id: 4
```

I'm wondering why my ids are suddenly 4?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ID field intermittently lost in custom point class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056414/id-field-intermittently-lost-in-custom-point-class)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed Boost.Geometry currently does not support transferring custom attributes to output geometries.

I cannot answer why the ids are 4, based on the snippets you give. Output points are either copied (from input) or created from default constructor, depending on geometry configuration of both input polygons.

Comment: Is there a way to inherit and/or modify operations like union to add support?

Comment: No. The algorithms assume the concept of a points to be creatable (this is documented) and also that two points with equivalent coordinates are equivalent. If you would have an algorithm that only copies (some of the) input points, you might have room for a "copy point" trait, but no such distinction exists in the library. In practice things would be far too complicated soon (when doing an intersection, do we copy points from the source regions, if possible? If you intersect to equivalent geometries with each other, which metadata will be present in the points of the resulting geometry?).