# How to assign boost geometry derived point type correctly?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

In my application I want to use a boost geometry point derived
type to carry additional data but fail to do so:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/geometries.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
namespace bg = boost::geometry;

using point_t = bg::model::d2::point_xy<double>;

struct taggedPoint_t : point_t
{
    taggedPoint_t(void* data) : mData(data) {}
    void* mData;
};

int main()
{
    point_t p1;
    bg::assign_values(p1, 1.0, 2.0); // OK

    taggedPoint_t p2(nullptr);
    bg::assign_values(p2, 2.0, 3.0); // Fails
}
```

Can someone shed some light on it how to do it correctly?
I also tried to register the point type:

```
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D(taggedPoint_t, double, cs::cartesian, x, y)
```

But that also failed.

[Sample code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b622d4bbc73cd7bf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the right way to adapt your point is to ignore it derived from a known geometry type and just adapt the public interface:

```
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET(taggedPoint_t, double, bg::cs::cartesian, x, y, x, y)
```

This works: [Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb4955d6e1825a12)

Of course you can also supply all the required traits and generalize:

```
template <typename Base> struct taggedPoint : Base {
    using base_type = Base;

    taggedPoint(void* data) : mData(data) {}
    void* mData;
};
```

Which you can them make "inherit" all the traits explicitly:

```
namespace boost::geometry::traits {
    template <typename B> struct tag<taggedPoint<B>>               : tag<B>               {};
    template <typename B> struct dimension<taggedPoint<B>>         : dimension<B>         {};
    template <typename B> struct coordinate_type<taggedPoint<B>>   : coordinate_type<B>   {};
    template <typename B> struct coordinate_system<taggedPoint<B>> : coordinate_system<B> {};
    template <typename B> struct access<taggedPoint<B>, 0> : access<B, 0> {};
    template <typename B> struct access<taggedPoint<B>, 1> : access<B, 1> {};
    template <typename B> struct access<taggedPoint<B>, 2> : access<B, 2> {};
} // namespace boost::geometry::traits
```

Now you can use it without further registration: [Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b1a0fd24469b788)

#### Caveat

[ID field intermittently lost in custom point class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29056414/id-field-intermittently-lost-in-custom-point-class/29065421#29065421) - your "rich point" data will usually be lost when used with standard Boost Geometry algorithms. See [Adam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29091624/85371) for hints on how to maybe use custom strategies (that's too advanced for me)

Answer (score 0):

`BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D` uses traits that are specialized for `bg::model::d2::point_xy`. You don't have those for your class. Specialize those traits for your type you can find them here:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp

This is not good idea as you will be writing code in `namespace bg`. But will work.
Use composition instead of inheritance to create `tagged_point_xy`. Like this

```
struct taggedPoint_t
{
    bg::point_t point;
    void* data;
};
```

Comment: I was contemplating to use compositition but decided against it because the derived class actually still is a point. The "data" member is a handle to the origin of the data.

Comment: Is the `data` pointing to a `point_t`?

Comment: It's a handle to a node of a tree representing the whole drawing. This node actually stores the point data and some other meta information.

Comment: If the node already stores point data then why not just use a pointer to the Node class and use `node->point` to get to the point if you need to operate on the point itself? if you want to operate on a copy then you can just use `bg::point_t point = node->point` and get a copy?

Comment: The representation is in text form and I need to do very many operations on the point.

Comment: I am asking because I am concerned about use after free when you store pointers in objects like this. That's all. If it is in text then it doesn't store `point_t`. If know the tree outlives all the `taggedPoint_t`s you should be good.

Comment: It's actually not a pointer in the real app but a handle to a node of the XML parser. I just wanted to make a stripped down version of the application. To be more explicit about my use case: The Tree is a SVG file (XML) and my app needs to keep the SVG/XML in sync with the boost::geometry processed stuff which is saved in a 2nd tree structure.

Comment: Is this like a UI application where the UI rendering happens using boost::geometry and the file format you load is XML?

Comment: Almost: The svg (xml) is parsed and evaluated. certain operations happen using boost geometry, others directly to the xml. in the end thesvg needs to be updated with the result of the calculation

Comment: Have you looked at the Model View Presenter pattern? It seems like a good candidate for your use case. The presenter in this case has an unordered_map from point to xml node.

Comment: My model is very similar to MVC. The main difference is: My model is storing the data in two trees which I need to keep in sync: 1. SVG/XML and a tree (vector of variants) with the most important data which is used when speed/performance is important. The view is completely separate: Inkscape.